# USB udc is always inactive

Tags: embedded-linux

I have encountered a problem with  a USB UDC linux driver. I'd like to connect our PXA320 based board to PC using g_ether and USB UDC.

Our board uses PXA320 with Linux-2.6.32 kernel.

I have enabled pxa27x UDC and g_ether on menuconfig and built kernel successfully.

But after I run "ifup usb0" and plug in the USB cable, PC detects the USB device (since D+ pull-up resistor is enabled) and sends "GET DESCRIPTOR" to the device. But the USB device(our board) does NOT respond.

I dumped some register values and found that the UDCCR is 0x1 which means UDC is enabled but is inactive.

The following are the debug messages I got:

```
ifup usb0

+++ ether - init

++++ usb_composite_register

+++ usb_gadget_register_driver

+++ dplus_pullup, on = 1

++++ composite_bind

+++ pxa_ep_alloc_request

--- pxa_ep_alloc_request

+++ eth_bind

g_ether gadget: using random self ethernet address

g_ether gadget: using random host ethernet address

usb0: MAC d6:81:e9:fa:0c:66

usb0: HOST MAC 7a:58:58:9a:bb:be

+++ eth_bind - CDC Subset/SAFE

+++ eth_bind - RNDIS plus ECM-or-Subset

+++ eth_bind - manufacturer = Linux 2.6.32.9 with pxa27x_udc

adding config #2 'RNDIS'/bf0059c0

adding 'rndis'/c7fcdf00 to config 'RNDIS'/bf0059c0

++++ composite_uevent

+++ usb_interface_id

--- usb_interface_id - id = 0

+++ usb_interface_id

--- usb_interface_id - id = 1

+++ pxa_ep_alloc_request

--- pxa_ep_alloc_request

adding config #1 'CDC Subset/SAFE'/bf00594c

+++ eth_do_config

adding 'cdc_subset'/c7fcdd80 to config 'CDC Subset/SAFE'/bf00594c

++++ composite_uevent

+++ usb_interface_id

--- usb_interface_id - id = 0

g_ether gadget: Ethernet Gadget, version: Memorial Day 2008

Memorial Day 2008, version: 

g_ether gadget: g_ether ready

registered gadget driver 'g_ether'

+++ should_enable_udc

--- should_enable_udc, put_on = 1

+++ udc_enable

+++ udc_clear_mask_UDCCR - udccr = 0x0, mask = 0x1

--- udc_clear_mask_UDCCR - udccr = 0x0

clk_pxa3xx_cken_enable - clk->cken = 0x14

+++ ep0_idle

+++ set_ep0state

state=WAIT_FOR_SETUP->WAIT_FOR_SETUP, udccsr0=0x000, udcbcr=0

+++ udc_set_mask_UDCCR

+++ ep_write_UDCCSR

+++ pio_irq_enable, index = 0

--- udc_enable

UDCCR(0x0) = 0x1

UDCICR0(0x4) = 0x3

UDCICR1(0x8) = 0xb8000000

UDCISR0(0xc) = 0x0

UDCISR1(0x10) = 0x0

UDCFNR(0x14) = 0x0

UDCOTGICR(0x18) = 0x0

UP2OCR(0x20) = 0xa0

UP3OCR(0x24) = 0x0

(0x100) = 0x200

(0x200) = 0x0

(0x300) = 0x43881454

(0x400) = 0x0

ICPR = 0x0

ICPR2 = 0x0

ICIP = 0x0

ICIP2 = 0x0

ICFP = 0x0

ICFP2 = 0x0

ICMR = 0x6b24c08

ICMR2 = 0x2000

ICLR = 0x0

ICLR2 = 0x0

ICCR = 0x1

ACCR = 0x0000321f

ACSR = 0x3003321f

AICSR = 0x0

CKEN_A = 0xffbfffff

CKEN_B = 0xffffffff
```

---

From the debug message, I can see that UDC clock is enabled (CKEN_A bit20), UDC interrupt is enabled (ICMR bit11) nad UDC is enabled (UDCCR bit0). But UDC is inactive(UDCCR bit1).

I have verified hardware by running Windows CE OS on the board and I could connect to PC via activesync.

I compared UDC registers between CE OS and Linux OS. CE version shows UDCCR is 0x3 which means UDC is active.

I don't understand why UDC is inactive in Linux. That bit in UDCCR is read only. 
Could anyone give me some hints on how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance